# Github : Does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, repository

I need to create a new remote to my own github account. But when I try to enter below code it gives error.

```
pushpika@pushpika-CodeMe MINGW32 ~/codezeroplus-1.0 (master)
$ git fetch pushpika@work 
fatal: 'pushpika@work' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

What I need to do now?

Comment: What is `pushpika@work`?

Comment: What is pushpika@work . .. Can we know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I think you will need to go with a  fresh start. At least to make sure that you have done the prerequs.  Follow along and you will be all set to `push , pull , branch , stash ....etc`.

First do the initial set up to connect with the upstream.

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"


git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

You can read more here  [github DOC](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/) .

.com 
Then , you will need to go to gihub and create a new repository.

After creating a new projct , it will have Clone URL. Somethign like this"you will need to link you local with the remote" :

```
git@github.com:mike/blah.git
```

locally do the following :

`CD`=> navigate to the project folder
and run  the following commands :

```
git init


git add .
# Adds the files in the local repository and stages 
#them for commit. To unstage a file, use 'git reset
#HEAD YOUR-FILE'.

git commit -m "First commit"
# Commits the tracked changes and prepares them to be pushed to a
#remote repository. To remove this commit and modify the file,
#use 'git reset --soft HEAD~1' and commit and add the file again.      


git remote add origin remote repository URL
# Sets the new remote



git push origin master
# pus to remote .
```

There are other ways to do this.But ,  for now this is the easiest way until get the hang of git. .

Comment: Hi @Chris The guy does not seem to have the big picture of this ... He said "create a new remote to my own github account" It seemed like he want to to start pushing stuff to github , but does not know how to connect with the upstream.

Comment: As for the git config, I am assuming he as not deployed keys or anything of that nature. I have seen it .. trust me  : ) Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to add a remote repository you need to perform a remote add first. The basic structure for the command is:

```
git remote add [shortname] [url]
```

If you've already done this step and you're still running into issues you should double check your `shortname` or `url` in your fetch. Use the `git remote -v` command to list the shortname and url pairing that Git has stored. For example,

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/schacon/ticgit (push)
```

There is a shorthand "origin" and its corresponding URL for push and fetch.

Check to make sure that your shorthand (I'm assuming that's how you're trying to use "pushpika@work") is correctly configured and/or use the full URL to access your repository.

PS.
There are helpful instructions in the [2.5 Git Basics - Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) documentation. Check the "Adding Remote Repositories" section for more information.

Comment: Links tend to go stale. It is better to post an example in the answer directly.

Comment: [Link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please edit your response to add the relevant commands directly to your answer.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Thank you TimA . :)  I just add "pushpika@work" to fetch . Earlier,  I really did not understand about fetch and push . But now I can understand. Thanks.